# Specific accounts cannot change AD passwords, affected users always told complexity requirements not met

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an organisation where I've had to do sitewide password changes for all users.

For the most part this has been fine, but there are three specific accounts where passwords cannot be changed, only reset by a domain admin.

When these three affected users attempt to change the password themselves, they are told the password does not meet the length/complexity/history requirements of the domain. This is the case whether they do it themselves on local Win10 domain-joined PCs, or if an admin tries it with `Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user` on the domain controller.

Resetting the password *does* work (both via dsa.mmc and using `Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset`)

In Default Domain Policy, the password requirements are: min length 8, history 0 (no history), complexity enabled, minimum age 0 days, max age 200 days, reversible encryption disabled.

I've used Group Policy Modelling on an affected user to confirm that this is the password policy applied to them both on their own computers, and on the DC where I've been trying Set-ADAccountPassword.

Sample passwords that are rejected with the does-not-meet-requirements message (again rejected on change, but accepted on reset) are `ThisIsATest0303!` and `r@9,@'Q-VL'B(f#'_C\AW5>_#z*Mn<"!w{,`.

Googling has failed me as in all results I can find, anyone else posting about similar issues really were trying passwords that failed the policy, or had min age 1 day. We have min age 0 - and it only affects a few users anyway. Other users, even within the same OU, can change their passwords fine.

I've scoured over all attributes of affected vs non-affected accounts and nothing has jumped out.

This was never a SBS environment or if it ever was, any remaining SBS OUs, policies etc have been long purged before I ever saw it, so I don't believe there's any residual stuff from that messing things up.

Keen for any pointers!

Comment: Are there any fine grained password policies assigned to their group?

Comment: The Default Domain Policy is not the ONLY place a password policy can be set via GPO - though it would be odd that it only affect some users if it was GPO related.

Comment: The fact that it can be reset, but not changed points to either a Password History problem (unlikely given those passwords) or a MinimumAge restriction (which would be covered by the "complexity" error).  My guess is that a GPO or FGPP actually has a Minimum Password Age configured somewhere.

Comment: `I've used Group Policy Modelling on an affected user to confirm that this is the password policy applied to them both on their own computers` When a user changes a password, the policy is enforced on the domain controller (computer not user!). So check each domain controller via password policy modelling.